# How can I compare a cell array with some values and return true if at least 1 value is found

Tags: arrays, excel, compare

I was at a job interview and I got a test to compare some cells containing a string of numbers with 4 other numbers and if at least ONE of those 4 numbers are in the string display 1 or 2 if false.

I tried some formulas like comparing 2 strings or each number but I couldn't figured it out. They wanted to be a formula in each cell in Col2.

The exercise was like: If Col1 contains at least one of the numbers 9, 10, 11 and 12 display 1 if true or 2 if false in Col2

Col1

A2 = 9,10,11,22,33

A3 = 10,34,55

A4 = 40, 78, 41, 26

I made a google sheet for more clarity: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GYnCQfjM2N-yLLQgHf2QRdaSLl14VB2liAJmv_SUXpE/edit?usp=sharing

Every row in Col1 was a string with selected options from a survey and if any of them were 9, 10, 11, 12 then Col2 should contain True or False or in that case 1 or 2. 
You can think as the numbers in the string as selected options: option1, option2, etc.

I was getting false answers because of numbers containing 9 seen as 9.

Comment: Sure no problem. I don't really know how to format text to be more clearly so i just put an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a formula that will work in Excel 2013+.

```
=IF(COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",""),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[.>=9 and .<= 12]"))>0,1,2)
```

It splits the values on the comma, and returns only those that meet the criteria.

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you'd need a different formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("," & {"9","10","11","12"} & ",",SUBSTITUTE(","&A1&","," ","")))),1,2)
```

This latter formula

- prepends and appends the string with a comma, so as to ensure that each entry is separated.
- "cleans" the string by removing any spaces
- uses an array constant (also with a comma prepended and appended) to look for the different contents
- Uses the `ISNUMBER` function to see if we found a match

[image]

Comment: Yes this worked for sure. I think their exercise was a bit to much for something like a junior position. Thanks.

Comment: @Serban101 Glad to help. I have edited my answer with a formula that will work in earlier versions of Excel, and may be more like what they were looking for.

Comment: Nice. The second formula actually is easier to edit for any other numbers. Thank you. Hope this help others too.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but something like this should work.:

```
sub test_ints ()
dim cl as range
dim ary as integer()
dim ans as boolean

set cl = rang(A2:A4)

for each i in cl
ary() = split(i.value)
 for j = 1 to UBOUND(len(ary))
   if ary(j) = 9 OR ary(j) = 10 OR ary(j) = 11 OR ary(j) = 12 then
     ans = true
      exit sub
   else
     ans = false
   end if
  next j
next i
end sub
```

Comment: Side note: "They wanted to be a formula in each cell in Col2."

Comment: Unfortunately my VBA knowledge is not great and this didn't work for me. Thank you still

Comment: oh I didn't catch the formula part.....@Serban101, this doesn't display an answer, just sets a boolean. In my skimming of the problem, I missed the whole formula in column b...